# How to emulate settings page

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Could someone please tell me how to emulate the elasticity of the settings page wherein a view controller can be dragged and released as if suspended by a rubber band.

eg. settings > wifi .. you can drag the text up and down despite only one line existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm right, you want this pretty bouncing effect at the top and bottom of a scroll view. This bouncing effect is activated by default on every scroll view you make on iOS 7. Like Preson said, you have to check on UIScrollView class reference. You will found some informations about bounce property (and also alwaysBounceHorizontal / alwaysBounceVertical).

You also might want to check [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the Settings page is different sections of a UITableView with "grouped" style. UITableView inherits from the UIScrollView class, which defines a default scrolling behaviour for views. So that we can see the bounce animation there.

If you want to emulate like in settings page you just need a table view only.